# if (day = day select) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, date, selected

```
 $('<option></option>')
            .attr('label', day)
            .attr('value', day)
            if(myDate.getDate() == day)
            {
            .attr('selected','selected')    
            }
            .html(day)
            .appendTo(daySelector);
```

What I want to do is run an if statement and if it is true make that day selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an object to accomplish this:

```
$('<option />', {
    selected: myDate.getDate() === day,
    value: day,
    text: day
}).appendTo(daySelector)
```

Here is an example of that style: http://jsfiddle.net/9hVeq/

Comment: Nice! Didn't know you can pass in an object of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put it in a **var** first ? Or am i missing something ?

```
var myOption = $('<option></option>').attr('label', day).attr('value', day); 

if( myDate.getDate() === day )
    myOption.attr('selected', 'selected'); 

myOption.html( day ); 
myOption.appendTo( daySelector );
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr` can take a function as a second parameter to determine what the value should be.

```
$('<option></option>').attr('label', day)
                      .attr('value', day)
                      .html(day)
                      .appendTo(daySelector)
                      .attr('selected', function() {
                          return (myDate.getDate() == day) ? "selected":null;
                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<option></option>')
            .attr('label', day)
            .attr('value', day)
            .attr('selected',(myDate.getDate() == day))
            .html(day)
            .appendTo(daySelector);
```

Should be enough. Alternatively you could set the value on the select element that holds the options:

```
daySelector.val( day );
```